# Get client ip from Google Network load balance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I can't use Google's HTTP load balance because it does not support web socket.

So my NGINX is running in Google Container Engine, behind Google Network Load Balance.

When the request arrives NGINX in docker container, it gets the IP of the NODE instead of the client ip.

> 2016/04/07 10:53:47 [error] 94#0: *73 access forbidden by rule,
>   client: 10.132.0.9

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue (websocket, need unique IPs) ... any luck so far?

Comment: Install NGINX load balance out of k8s, and add `X-Forwarded-For` there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the client IP when using Network Load balancer with Kubernetes is a known limitation. You can refer to this [issue bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/10921) for updates and workarounds.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/27

Answer (score 0):

You get the IP of the "gce network load balancer" in the nginx  logs?

since your question is not really clear, i presume your problem is in the nginx configuration.
<s>try adding x-forwarded-for option in nginx.conf</s> 
more clear:
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

check the official google post
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/https-load-balancing-nginx

Comment: Google Http Load Balancer does not support web socket. It is the NGINX running in POD can not get the real ip,  has nothing to do with the `X-Forwarded-For` header